# fogbugz select drop downs

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know the code fogbugz uses for styling their selects?  I'm interested in getting some firefox functionality (when a fixed select width is set for the select, the options width show up expanded to fit long option values).

It looks like fogbugz is using a select still, but they've added in an input that shows the current value and maintains the fixed width.  I can't find the code that does all this however.  It's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using some AJAX and it is not actually a select list, it is more akin to the auto complete drop down like Google uses on its front page.  YUI, jQuery UI, ExtJS, etc all have similar functionality if you are looking for a toolset.